# Проверка авторизации и редирект

Tags: javascript, react-router, react-router-dom

Я новичок в react.  Можете подсказать как делать проверку авторизации на React 17 для этой задачи?
[image: задача]

Answer (score 0):

Сложно ответить кодом, дабы не писать целое приложение, или его половину

Для решения вашей задачи вам нужно ознакомиться с **реакт-роутером**
(например тут: https://reactdev.ru/libs/react-router/)

И с **контекстом** в реакт:
https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/context.html

И крайне желательно конечно ещё изучить стейт менеджер типа `Mobx` или `Redux`